# How to sort collection according particular field value of POJO?

Tags: java, sorting, collections, pojo

I have one below mentioned class (`POJO`),

```
public class DummyPage{

   public DummyPage(int id, String month){
     this.id = id;
     this.month = month;
   }

   public DummyPage(){
   }

   private int id
   private String  month;

   //getter and setters
}
```

and also piece of code

```
public static void main(String[] args){

   List<DummyPage> list = new ArrayList<DummyPage>();
   list.add(new DummyPage(1,"March"));
   list.add(new DummyPage(2,"September"));
   list.add(new DummyPage(3,"December"));
   list.add(new DummyPage(4,"May"));
   list.add(new DummyPage(5,"April"));
   list.add(new DummyPage(6,"January"));
   list.add(new DummyPage(7,"August"));
   list.add(new DummyPage(8,"March"));
   list.add(new DummyPage(9,"December"));
   list.add(new DummyPage(10,"October"));
   list.add(new DummyPage(11,"July"));
   list.add(new DummyPage(12,"November"));
   list.add(new DummyPage(13,"February"));
   list.add(new DummyPage(14,"May"));
   list.add(new DummyPage(15,"June"));      

}
```

My actual `POJO` have more fields and also actually `list` have more objects.

**Expected Result :**
I need to sort declared `list` according to month name wise. 
All objects with `January` month name must come `first` in output list.
 
All objects with `February` month name must come `second` in output list.
etc.. for all the months.

Which is the best way to sort these type of objects in given manner? Can I use `Comparator`? If yes, how can I implement it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Just one hint, you can pass custom comparator to Collections.sort method

Comment: Write a `Comparator` backed by the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum.

Comment: Hi @Karna, Thanks, but I know about comparator..and also I have seen many examples on it on Google. but can't find the way for this requirement using it.

Comment: @Robby Cornelissen, Thank but I did not get what you are trying to sa.. any example code snap or reference link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a custom comparator and pass it to `Collections.sort()`, as suggested by [@Robby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27645686/how-to-sort-collection-according-particular-field-value-of-pojo/27645726#comment43709488_27645686), you can use Month enum like

```
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<DummyPage> {
    @Override
    public int compare(DummyPage o1, DummyPage o2) {
        return Month.valueOf(o1.getMonth().toUpperCase()).compare(Month.valueOf(o2.getMonth().toUpperCase()));
    }
}
```

and

```
Collections.sort(list , new CustomComparator());
```

Also looks like you already have month number in `DummyPage.id` field, it can be used directly in `compare` method of comparator. Or if you are looking for how to convert month name to number, you can use `SimpleDateFormat`

```
public int convertMonthToNumber(String month){
     Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(month);
     Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
     cal.setTime(date);
     return cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is the question only. What can be the logic for comparing months? I can easily compare `id`.

Comment: @Karna Probably need to uppercase the months if you use the enum: `Month.valueOf(o1.getMonth().toUpperCase())`

Comment: Also, for performance reasons, I would advise against the solution using `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar`.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Yup, Also Month enum is introduced in Java 8, so `SimpleDateFormat` would be a good choice if OP is earlier version

Comment: @Karna If OP is using an earlier version, it would be trivial to implement a month enum: `public enum Month {JANUARY, FEBRUARY, MARCH, APRIL, MAY, JUNE, JULY, AUGUST, SEPTEMBER, OCTOBER, NOVEMBER, DECEMBER}` See, it fits in a comment ;-)

Comment: Yup.. So OP have freedom of choosing between `month` or `simpkedateformat`

Comment: yes.. I am using earlier version and I have already created ENUM before you commented ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the month String to a calendar month and then you can compare them.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<DummyPage> {
    @Override
    public int compare(DummyPage object1, DummyPage object2) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("MMM").parse(object1.getMonth()));
        int object1Month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
        cal.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("MMM").parse(object2.getMonth()));
        int object2Month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
        return object1Month - object2Month;
    }
}

Collections.sort(list , new CustomComparator());
```

Comment: OP already have month number in `Dummypage.id` field, it can be used instead of deriving same from month name

Answer (score -1):

```
...
List< DummyPage > sortedList = new ArrayList< DummyPage >(list);
Collections.sort(sortedList, new Comparator<DummyPage>() {
        public int compare(DummyPage p1, DummyPage p2) {
           return  Month.valueOf(p1.getMonth()) .compareTo(Month.valueOf(p2.getMonth());
           //Wrong : return p1.getMonth().compareTo(p2.getMonth());
        }
});

// Now the sortedList is sorted Based on the month
```

Comment: it will be a string comparison, not month comparison

Comment: It will give `April` first month, not `January`.

Comment: Oops my bad . Need to be  
**Month.valueOf(p1.getMonth())
.compareTo(Month.valueOf(p2.getMonth())**.
I have edited the compare method